# Android: Black screen when starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I use Android Studio.

I have an activity call `NewGame` which includes bunch of animation. From `NewGame` I want to start another activity called `PetInfo`, but for some reasons this activity doesn't start. Instead, there is a black screen appears and it doesn't go away no matter how long I wait. But when this happens, in Android Monitor if I clicks on the red X (Terminate Application) then the black screen goes away and my `PetInfo` activity comes up.

So I don't know what is the deal with the black screen. Not sure if it is because of the `NewGame` activity has too much stuff?

Any idea? Thanks!

**Edited:** Add some code

**`NewGame`** activity

```
public class NewGame extends Activity {
GameView game_view;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    game_view = new GameView(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
  }


  // This method executes when the player starts the game
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Tell the gameView resume method to execute
    game_view.resume();
  }

  // This method executes when the player quits the game
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Tell the gameView pause method to execute
    game_view.pause();
  }

  // Start new activity
  public void createInfo(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PetInfo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

**`activity_new_game.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="OK"
    android:onClick="createInfo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**`PetInfo`** activity

```
public class PetInfo extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("test", "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pet_info);
  }
}
```

and **`activity_pet_info.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Pet Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pet_name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/pet_birth"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pet_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: how do you call "createInfo"?

Comment: onClick from a Button in activity_new_game.xml. I added that code.

Comment: your activity_pet_info.xml has errors in it

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

<!-- views that will live in the relative layout -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the proper way to place views inside the RelativeLayout in your PetInfo layout file.

Comment: I changed to this but the same thing is still happening... Thanks though!

Comment: try setting a background color on the relativelayout and see if you can see the color you set, that way you will at least know that the layout is being inflated correctly.

Comment: I got it. The problem for me is I have thread running and I didn't stop the thread so the thread was never joined. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Because of `game_view.pause()` in `onPause` in `NewGame Activity`. May be your `pause()` does huge process in main thread.